# How to combine Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine two Pandas series, A and B, to get C:

```
A:
1    odd
2    Nan   
3    odd
4    Nan   
5    odd
6    Nan   

B:
1    Nan   
2    even
3    Nan   
4    even
5    Nan   
6    even
```

C should look like the following (where there is a Nan value in A then the value in B should be used and vice-versa)

```
C:
1    odd
2    even
3    odd
4    even
5    odd
6    even
```

There is probably a simple way to do this but it escapes me...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), which takes the values from the calling Series (`A`) first, and updates NaNs in `A` with the corresponding value from `B`:

```
In [76]: A.combine_first(B)
Out[83]: 
0     odd
1    even
2     odd
3    even
4     odd
5    even
dtype: object
```